# Two boxes in splitlayout in R shiny app are misaligned. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have two numericInput boxes, allowing for the input of the min and max (range) of a numeric variable. I have tried using splitLayout, which works but the boxes are misaligned when I include a label for the boxes.

The code is below

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

        #fluidRow(
        splitLayout(

            variable <- faithful$waiting,

            numericInput(paste("Min"), 
                         #round = TRUE,
                         label = h5(c("test")),
                         min = round(min(variable, na.rm=TRUE)),
                         max = round(max(variable, na.rm=TRUE))-1,
                         value = round(min(variable, na.rm=TRUE))

            ), ## end slider input

            numericInput(paste("Min"), 
                         #round = TRUE,
                         label = h5(""),
                         min = round(min(variable, na.rm=TRUE))+1,
                         max = round(max(variable, na.rm=TRUE)),
                         value = round(max(variable, na.rm=TRUE))


            )
    )
)
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run the code, you will see that the boxes are misaligned.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a label for one box, which pushes it down, with no equivalent label for the other box. To push the second box down, you need to include something that will read as label without showing anything. I used an HTML break:

```
 numericInput(paste("Min"), 
                     #round = TRUE,
                     label = h5(HTML("<br/>")),
                     min = round(min(variable, na.rm=TRUE))+1,
                     max = round(max(variable, na.rm=TRUE)),
                     value = round(max(variable, na.rm=TRUE))
```